# combobox.SelectedItem.ToString shows the result "System.Data.DataRowView"

Tags: vb.net, combobox

When I want to to take the item that the user selected from the combobox, I get this result:

```
"System.Data.DataRowView"
```

When I use `combobox.SeletedIndex.ToString` that gives me the index as a string.

When I use `combobox.SelectedValue.ToString` that gives me the value.

But when I use `combobox.SelectedItem.ToString` that gives me the above message.

Here is my code for the combobox:

```
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Category"    
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnection)    
Dim ds As New DataSet    
da.Fill(ds, "Category")    
With categoryidcbox    
.DataSource = ds.Tables("Category")    
.DisplayMember = "Names"    
.ValueMember = "Category_Id"    
.SelectedIndex = 0    
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Dim row As DataRowView = DirectCast(categoryidcbox.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
MessageBox.Show("Clicked on " & row("Names").ToString & _
                " ID " & row("Category_Id").ToString)
```

Comment: @GabrielBlanco You probably need to document your question better.  If you notice from my example, I don't have any `ToString` calls, so my code should not be showing any "System.Data.DataRowView" messages.  What message are you trying to display?

Comment: i wan to take the ITEM to make it as file name .. like this      DimFileToCopy As String
        Dim NewCopy As String

        FileToCopy = TextBox1.Text
        NewCopy = "C:\Users\wisam\Desktop\project\'" + subcategorycbox.SelectedItem.ToString + "'\'" + "';"

Comment: @GabrielBlanco Which field from the row are you looking to use for that SelectedItem value?  My answer should pretty much still help you solve this problem.  Replace `subcategorycbox.selecteditem` with my row variable.

Comment: now i get this error >> Conversion from string "'" to type 'Double' is not valid.>>> my code now like this NewCopy = "C:\Users\wisam\Desktop\project\'" + "Clicked on " & row("Names") & " ID " & row("Category_Id") + "'"

Comment: @GabrielBlanco I don't see where in your code you are using a double.  Use a `ToString()` on those row variables.

Comment: @GabrielBlanco If a post answers your question, feel free to click the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the SORTED property of the combobox. It should be FALSE when data is populated from database. If true then the said error happens.